Guidance needed to choose books to further my Critical thinking
Hi all I have this list of books that I have scrapped of internet and used CHatGPT to curate. I am sure it is good (or closing that) but wanted to get idea if these are anyway helpful. (edit: This statement has an inconsistency as pointed in comment. Yet I urge you to provide me your perspective). I have read books like "Predictably Irrational" "Thinking, Fast and Slow" from the list. I just want to further my understanding without repeating the content.
Can you tell which books should I use?



No.
Book Title
Author(s)




1
Critical Thinking: A Beginner’s Guide
Jennifer Wilson


2
Wait, What?: And Life’s Other Essential Questions
James E. Ryan


3
Think Smarter
Michael Kallet


4
Brain Power
Karl Albrecht


5
The Art of Thinking Clearly
Rolf Dobelli


6
Being Logical
D.Q. McInerny


7
Predictably Irrational
Dr. Dan Ariely


8
A More Beautiful Question
Warren Berger


9
A Rulebook for Arguments
Anthony Weston


10
Thinking, Fast and Slow
Daniel Kahneman


11
The Organized Mind
Daniel J. Levitin


12
Don’t Believe Everything You Think
Thomas E. Kida


13
The Decision Book
Mikael Krogerus et al.


14
Weaponized Lies
Daniel J. Levitin


15
The Demon-Haunted World
Carl Sagan, Ann Druyan


16
How to Think About Weird Things
Theodore Schick, Lewis Vaughn


17
The 5 Elements of Effective Thinking
Edward B. Burger, Michael Starbird


18
Superforecasting: The Art and Science of Prediction
Philip E. Tetlock, Dan M. Gardner


19
The Skeptics' Guide to the Universe
Dr. Steven Novella


20
Thinking in Bets
Annie Duke


21
Nudge: Improving Decisions About Health, Wealth, and Happiness
Richard H. Thaler, Cass R. Sunstein


22
The Black Swan
Nassim Nicholas Taleb


23
The Logic of Scientific Discovery
Karl Popper


24
Good Arguments: What the Art of Debating Can Teach Us About Listening Better and Disagreeing Well
Bo Seo


25
The hidden traps of persuasion. Decode the deception of fallacies, cognitive biases and rhetorical devices
Prasad A S



Edit 1:
Hi @Doubleknot,
Thank you for pointing out the subtle logical inconsistency in my question. Your observation serves as a valuable reminder of the need to scrutinize not just what we ask but how we ask it. Though I phrased my confidence in the list as "good," it was not meant to close the door on critique. Rather, I am deeply open to evaluation, correction, and any feedback that might challenge my preconceptions.
Your comment also seems to caution me against overthinking—a fair warning, given the circularity inherent in using one's mind to evaluate itself. It reminds me of a saying: "A mirror cannot reflect its own surface." Perhaps, in my journey to refine my thinking, I have unintentionally tread into this paradox.
To clarify, my question arises from a broader aspiration: to understand the human brain and decision-making in a deeper, interdisciplinary way. This is my first deliberate step into philosophy, and I see it as a necessary companion to the behavioral sciences. Decisions, after all, are not made in isolation; they are colored by the moral frameworks and cognitive patterns we often overlook. Books like Predictably Irrational helped me dissect biases in the financial and behavioral realm, while Thinking, Fast and Slow illuminated the dual processes of cognition. But these are fragments of a larger mosaic I am striving to piece together.
As for your point about time constraints, I appreciate it, though I hold a belief that what I deeply engage with can translate into meaningful action. My focus isn’t on speed or breadth but on the transformative depth of learning—reading not just for knowledge, but for understanding that is actionable and enduring.
I apologize for not including my goals or time considerations in the original post; this was an oversight I will address in the future. Now, with this added context, I would greatly value your revisited insights on my question. Thank you for your thoughtful engagement—it is conversations like these that make the journey all the more enriching.
Hi @Jo Wehler,
Thank you for your insightful comment. I wholeheartedly agree that critical thinking is honed most effectively through practice—through the deliberate and conscious application of these principles in real-world situations. However, I also believe that every journey must have its beginning, and this curated list of books represents my initial stepping stones. It is neither static nor definitive, but rather a living, evolving tool that I will refine as my understanding deepens.
For example, it was only through my early reading that I first encountered the concept of logical fallacies—a revelation that has since reshaped the way I engage in discussions and evaluate ideas. Even in this post, as @Double Knot kindly pointed out, I’ve made a contradictory statement, which underscores how much I still have to learn. Yet, this acknowledgment is, I believe, part of the practice—observing, correcting, and striving to do better each time.
This list, then, is not a destination but a guide—a compass pointing toward greater intellectual clarity. It serves to equip me with the tools to challenge assumptions, refine reasoning, and expand my perspective. I deeply appreciate your recommendation of Karl Popper’s work; I will be prioritizing it as I move forward.
With this in mind, are there any additional books or thinkers you would recommend to further cultivate critical thinking? Your guidance is greatly appreciated, and I value the time you’ve taken to engage with my question.

Re your "I am sure it is good (or closing that) but wanted to get idea if these are anyway helpful.", if you're already sure they're good then they're helpful by the colloquial meaning of 'good' here. With your own mind, you grasp at your own mind. What is not illusory turns into illusion...

@WhatsappBackup IMO it is not the right way to improve one's critical thinking by collecting a long list of mostly unknown authors - with the help of ChatGPT? - and then to ask the community which book to read. - Critical thinking is more effectively improved by using it in real situations of life than reading about it in books. - Nevertheless, In any case I consider to grapple with the ideas of Popper, cf. no. 23, to be a good start.

@DoubleKnot I don't understand your comment. First you suggest that the question is already answered, because the books are deemed good and therefore helpful. Then you say: With your own mind, you grasp at your own mind. What is not illusory turns into illusion.  Here you warn the OP against their own mind and hint at the usefulness of seeking help from other minds. If it is not to ask other minds, then what is this forum for? So in your mind, is this a good queston or a bad question??

@Philomath I just warned OP about their logical problem even after reading some of the books in the list. Indeed this neutral question (no one seems ever downvoted or upvoted yet) itself could be turned into a philosophical question about how to choose what to read in general (say, how many out of the list if no time for all which also depends on OP's undisclosed personal goal to achieve, are there other books needed outside the list for OP's specific goal, etc), if not turned into another book of personal reading journey to be added in the said list, from other minds' help like this site...

@DoubleKnot Got it! And a good warning it is indeed!

Seems a pretty austere list. Anything funny in there?

@DoubleKnot I have addressed your queries in the question. Could you look at it and provide me guidance. I want to add that your poetic writing style was refreshing.

@JoWehler I have addressed your concern in the post can you please provide your feedback on it. I appreciate you taking time to read it.

@Olivier5 these works are indeed dense and academically rigorous, I find humor to be a deeply subjective experience. What one finds amusing, another might overlook entirely. For example, I find humor in intellectual ironies—like the moment after reading Thinking, Fast and Slow when I spent months analyzing how often I blindly accepted statistics. Reflecting on the accuracy of Dr. Kahneman’s insight, I couldn’t help but laugh at how true it was for me. Each book was selected based on its depth and relevance to understanding critical thinking, decision-making, or human psychology.

I am acquainting myself with the rules and ethos of this space, aspiring to craft exchanges that are not just queries but meaningful dialogues. Your insights would be invaluable as I learn to navigate this forum with greater clarity and purpose.

@AmunRa #23 in your list is the only one I read. It's thoroughly excellent.
